# RIA Services why does VS 2010 not generate an App.config when there is no EF model?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, web-config, app-config, wcf-ria-services

We always generate our RIA services as a "WCF RIA Services Class Library".

When we generated one for POCO, without first adding an EF model, we noticed the App.config was not generated.

After testing we found the settings are only added to App.config if the App.config file already exists in the project.

Is this just a bug in VS 2010?